# PivotViewer V2 with CXML shows no images

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer, cxml-collectionxml

I used the PivotViewer V1, created a server, which sends CXML, DZC, DZI and the image tiles to the client.
Everything works just fine for PivotViewer V1.

Now I want to switch to V2 of the PivotViewer. To get started I downloaded the CXML example [here](http://xpert360.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/silverlight-5-rc-getting-started-with-pivotviewer/) ("HELLO OLD WORLD!").
When I ran the example without any modification to the code, all the meta is loaded but there are no pictures anyway:

[image: No images are displayed within the pivotviewer]

As I took a look at the source I see that a CXML from http://www.xpert360.net/SQLBits/Collection.cxml is loaded. So I set up my Fiddler. As expected, there is that CXML request, but still no request to any DZC, DZI or ImageTile:

[image: There is no request for any images]

As I inspect the object structure of the `PivotViewerItems` generated by the CXML parser, I was wondering about, why the tile count is equal to zero:

[image: Tilecount == 0? Why?]

I also tried with my own collection (which, works for PivotViewer V1), without any success.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly got the solution, by testing some other stuff...
I was using `"C:\Users\Daniel Huhn\SL5Test\Bin\Debug\SL5TestPage.html"` as my HTML page to host the site.

After using a ASP.NET web Project to host the App (`http://localhost:5453/SL5TestPage.aspx`), all images are displayed :)

Answer (score 0):

What does your code behind look like when you are mapping the CxmlCollectionSource to the PV?  Here is another sample for you to compare against: http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/09/to-cxml-or-not-to-cxml/

Comment: Example at http://tonyc.me/tBGU8l doesn't work either. Code's the same everywhere.